# Can I make my iPhone vibrate louder or stronger?

Tags: iphone, ios, vibrate

I often have to turn my iPhone ringer off. This is ok when I’m at my desk because when it vibrates it is loud enough on the desk that I never miss a call. My problem is that when I am walking and have the phone in my pocket, I almost always miss the call.

This is becoming a real issue for me and I wondered if I could make the vibration louder, but [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111921/iphone-vibrate-level) indicates not.

I have an iPhone 6s on iOS 10.3.3, and that question is about 4 years old now, so I'm hoping things have changed.

Is this still the case? If its still the case, is there any way I can make the vibration stronger or something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you can’t make your iPhone vibrate louder. But since your real issue is that you’re not noticing the vibration while it’s in your pocket, you could try creating a custom vibration that is more noticeable to you.

**Creating a custom vibration**

Follow these steps:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap on Sounds
3. Tap on the *Ringtone* option
4. Tap on *Vibration*
5. Tap on *Create New Vibration*
6. Now tap the centre of your screen to record a pattern you think will be more noticeable (I’m thinking two or three long presses will be more obvious when it’s in your pocket, but at least you can try different things until you find one that suits you)
7. When finished, tap on Save in the top right-hand corner
8. Give your new custom vibration a name
9. Make sure it’s now selected as your vibration type for your ringtone
10. Exit Settings

**Note: -** All vibrations you create appear in a list of custom vibrations and are available for **all** events, not just your ringtone (e.g. you can select it for reminders, texts, etc).

**[EDIT - Select or create custom vibrations for individual Contacts]**

Another option that may interest you is to select or create a custom vibration for people in your contacts. To do this:

1. Open Contacts
2. Select a contact
3. Tap on *Edit* in the top right corner
4. Tap on either *Ringtone* or *Text Tone*
5. Tap on *Vibration*
6. Select one of the standard or custom vibrations
7. Go back and tap on *Done*